# multiply a dataframe element-wise by a row

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` and a row vector named `mult` of the same size as a row in `df`.

I need to multiply each row of `df` by `mult` as element-wise multiplication. But I do not want to write a loop, as there are probably faster ways to do this.

Here are my failed attempts:

```
df = data.frame(matrix(nrow = 5, ncol = 5))

df[,] = 5 

mult = as.data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5))

df * t(mult[1:5,])
```

Whether I transpose `mult[1:5,]`, I get the same result.

The correct answer should be a dataframe of five rows of `5 10 15 20 25`.

However, I am getting the result as if I am doing element-wise multiplying by `mult` as a column vector.

```
5   5   5   5   5
10  10  10  10  10
15  15  15  15  15
20  20  20  20  20
25  25  25  25  25
```

Multiplying a row at a time works, but that will involve a loop.

I have searched the SO and found `sweep()`, but it does not seem to work in my case.

Comment: Try `t(t(df) * mult[[1]])`.

Comment: This works like a charm. May I ask how does mult[[1]] converts mult into a row, and why is double transpose necessary? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df * matrix(rep(mult[,1], NROW(df)), nrow = NROW(df), byrow = TRUE)
#  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
#1  5 10 15 20 25
#2  5 10 15 20 25
#3  5 10 15 20 25
#4  5 10 15 20 25
#5  5 10 15 20 25
```

Answer (score 1):

We could just replicate the 'mult'

```
df * mult[,1][col(df)]
#  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
#1  5 10 15 20 25
#2  5 10 15 20 25
#3  5 10 15 20 25
#4  5 10 15 20 25
#5  5 10 15 20 25
```